# Get selecteditems value from listview which has datas binded with eval

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, telerik, eval

I bind my data to listview using eval. like that :

```
<telerik:RadListView ID="lvDSTableSelection" runat="server" AllowMultiItemSelection="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lvDSTableSelection_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableViewState="true" >

         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CssClass="selectedButtons" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Font-Underline="false" >
                <p ><%# Container.DataItem %></p>
             </asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemTemplate>

            <p ><%# Container.DataItem %></p>
       </SelectedItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListView>
```

How can I get selecteditems data at code behind. I tried this in selecteditemchanged event

```
lvDSTableSelection.SelectedItems[0].DataItem.ToString() ;
```

When I debugged code I realizde that my SelectedItems[0] count is 1 but SelectedItems[0].DataItem is null. I suppose it is about with usage of eval.

How can I get selecteditems data from codebehind?

Comment: Are you rebinding the data on postback or before trying to access the selected item?

Comment: No. I use if (!IsPostBack){Populate(); }. But I use EnableViewState="true" in listview property.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this issue with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with your code but not able to reproduce this issue.

Please try with the below code snippet.

ASPX

```
<telerik:RadListView ID="lvDSTableSelection" runat="server" AllowMultiItemSelection="true" EnableViewState="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CssClass="selectedButtons" runat="server" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Font-Underline="false" OnClick="lvDSTableSelection_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <p ><%# Container.DataItem %></p>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SelectedItemTemplate>
        <p><%# Container.DataItem %></p>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListView>
```

ASPX.CS

```
protected void lvDSTableSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str1 = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
}
```